# New array overwriting global array

Tags: javascript

I have a global array like:

```
var myArray = [];
```

And it has various elements in it. I need to create a new array with the same contents and then reverse it like this:

```
newArray = myArray;
newArray = newArray.reverse();
```

However when I do this, it reverses both the myArray and newArray.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on what you have in array. If it's simple primitive values like numbers, then `.slice` is enough to clone an array. If you have objects in array, you have to make a deep copy of array, and `slice` will make only a shallow copy. If it's what you need then use `.slice` method.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/450bd6wj/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because both your arrays are referenced to the same object. To get rid of it you have to clone it with slice..

```
var myArray = [1,2];
var newArray = myArray.slice(0)
newArray.reverse();
```